# how's the database management software like navicat select a large number of data from table

Tags: c++, linux, database, navicat

I am writing a c++ program in Linux platform.This program is something like linux-mini-navicat,which can connect to different database(postgresql,mysql,mssql,oracle) and execute sql.And the program start an interface server(thrift) for client connect and execute sql command.

When I execute "select * from table" which have a lot of data,maybe a million or 10 million or more,my program is terminated by linux before returning data back to client, duing to it out of memory.

I am curious about how navicat achive that,and how can I achive that in my program?

Hope I make my question clear.

Comment: Maybe by not storing all the data in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is no need to retrieve (and hold in memory) all data from the big table in one go. If you are displaying query results, you could fetch enough data to fill the table on the screen, and then download it when user scrolls the table. If you develop some analysis algorithm, you still could analyze table data in chunks. See documentation on scrollable cursors for your database engine.